# Is showCameraRoll and showFilters on Android impossible to configure?

Tags: photoeditorsdk

The iOS SDK camera has the possibility to configure `showCameraRoll` and `showFilters` as well as dedicated options for background color both for the editor, the camera and the menu bar. I couldn't find those options in the Android SDK. Also there is no magic menu item available on Android. Am I overlooking something or is this simply impossible to configure currently?

I'm the creator of https://github.com/interw3bs/photo-editor-sdk-react-native and trying to reach you for a couple of days. By answering my questions I could make the react native binding better :)

Comment: iOS and Android are different platforms with different functionality. It is certainly possible that one function is more sophisticated on one than on the other. Since Android phones differ majorly in hardware from one to another, the base functionality of the SDK is ofter more bare-bone.

Comment: Hi Michel, unfortunately it seems like this question will possibly be closed because it doesn't suit the site's format.

Comment: Guys im trying to implement a react native binding for the photo editor sdk and was simply wondering if I'm overlooking something or interpreted the documentation correctly. Specifically showCameraRoll and showFilters should be possible on both platforms IMHO.

Comment: You might have better luck if you explained what "the photo editor sdk" is.  Are you referring to [this commercial product](https://www.photoeditorsdk.com/)? If so, what evidence do you have that they are looking at Stack Overflow for questions to answer?

Comment: @CommonsWare yes, sorry, I thought this was a given due to the tags.
Thats what they say on their page :) 
> Please use Stackoverflow for all technical questions and integration issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am Sven form the PhotoEditor SDK, there are currently no settings like `showCameraRoll` and `showFilters` in the Android SDK. 
But the customer can simply remove it from the layout (Override of the XML and set visibility to gone).

I understand this is a problem for cross-platform plugins like yours. We will consider to integrate it into feature versions.

The magic feature is not a feature of the Android SDK because it is an iOS native feature the iOS SDK is using.